# Does ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback overwrite existing certificate validation in .Net?

Tags: c#, wcf, certificate

I'm implementing a WCF client that will use certificates for secure communication. The server will also present a certificate and I would like to implement the `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` simply to log the certificate from the server. Here's an example:

```
using System.Net;

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += RemoteCertificateValidate;

private bool RemoteCertificateValidate(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors error)
{
    // certificate logging goes here
}
```

My question is this, will the default certificate validation that is done by the .Net framwork still happen? Or will my implementation of the `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` overwrite the .Net certificate validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know the default certificate validation is done prior to the ServerCertificateValidationCallback.

You can follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24698982/execute-default-certificate-validation-when-overriding-servicepointmanager-serve) for more information.